# System.NotSupportedException With compiled LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that Queries a Database (I am using LINQ to SQL). The query works fine as a stand alone, but when I put it into a compiled query I get an error when calling it.

The error,

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in
>   System.Data.Linq.dll Additional information: Member
>   'StaffManager.Employee.Key' there is no conversion to SQL that are
>   supported.

This is the query that I have been using and WORKS.

```
    public static ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeesInSection(DatabaseDataContext database, string section)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Employee>(database.Staff_Time_TBLs
            .Where(staff => staff.Section_Data == section)
            .Select(staff => new Employee(staff.Staff_No ?? -1,
                staff.Staff_Name_First, staff.Staff_Name_Second))
            .ToList()
            .GroupBy(staff => staff.Key)
            .Select(staff => staff.First())
            .OrderBy(staff => staff.Key)
            .ToList());
    }
```

This is the `Employee class` which the `Key` seems to be giving problems.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName;

        public Employee(int key, string first = null, string second = null)
        {
            Key = key;
            FirstName = first;
            SecondName = second;
        }
    }
```

And this is the compiled query and the method calling the query,

```
public static class CompiledQueries
    {
        public static Func<DatabaseDataContext, string, IEnumerable<Employee>>        
            sectionEmployess = CompiledQuery.Compile((DatabaseDataContext database, string section) =>
                                 database.Staff_Data_TBLs.Where(staff => staff.Section_Data == section)
                                 .Select(staff => new Employee(staff.Staff_No ?? -1,
                                  staff.Staff_Name_First, staff.Staff_Name_Second))
                                 .ToList()
                                 .GroupBy(staff => staff.Key)
                                 .Select(staff => staff.First())
                                 .OrderBy(staff => staff.Key));                                     

}
```

And the method, the error occurs here.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeesInSection(DatabaseDataContext database, string section)
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Employee>
                 (CompiledQueries.sectionEmployess(database, section));
        }
```

I am at a loss as to why this won't work in a compiled query ,but works fine in just a plain LINQ query. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: You converted your query into a list, it's no longer a compilable query.

Comment: @JeffMercado, are you talking about this `.ToList()` ?

Comment: @JeffMercado, still getting the exact same runtime error.

Comment: LINQ isn't an ORM. It doesn't connect to databases, it's just a language. What *ORM* are you using? Linq to SQL ? Entity Framework ? EF won't allow queries that can't be mapped to SQL (eg if you make function calls with no SQL equivalent). L2S will load any data it can in memory and continue as LINQ to Objects - quite unfortunate if it ends up loading half the database

Comment: Your code mixes up Entity Framework and LINQ to Objects, ie a plain old in-memory List. The call to `ToList()` before grouping is a problem itself, it means you found you couldn't perform whatever grouping you wanted as SQL  and instead of fixing it, you just loaded everything in memory. You could load the top values per employee from `Staff_Time_TBLs` and *after* the last `OrderBy` do a `ToList().Select` to generate employees` from the query results

Comment: As for your exact problem, before `ToList()` you have a LINQ to EF query that generates SQL. After that, you have a LINQ to Objects query that just iterates over the result list. When you try to compile the combined queries (to improve the performance loss caused by loading everything perhaps?) you force LINQ to generate a SQL query, which is impossible to do when the *second* query deals with objects

Comment: Why `.ToList().GroupBy(staff => staff.Key).Select(staff => staff.First())` ? Did you want to retrieve *distinct* entries per  key? You could write `.Select(staff => new {staff.Staff_No ,staff.Staff_Name_First, staff.Staff_Name_Second}).OrderBy(staff => staff.Staff_No).Distinct()`. After that I think you could directly return Employees without even a call to `ToList`. Even if you have to use `ToList` before `.Select(staff => new Employee(..)` it doesn't hurt because only data you actually need is loaded

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am using LINQ to SQL. Each key is a unique value, so by default I will be return distinct values. As to your question as to wht the `ToList()`. I could not tell you other than that is the only way I could get the query to work for me. I certainly am open to suggestions as I am still very new to LINQ. Thanks for the helpBTW

Comment: so what happens if you remove the `.ToList()` line from the `CompiledQuery` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer to this was that I was trying to use the `CompiledQuery` class on something that it can't be used on. LINQ can only use this class when SQL is involved and this part of the query below is not.

```
.Select(staff => new Employee(staff.Staff_No ?? -1,
                    staff.Staff_Name_First, staff.Staff_Name_Second))
                .ToList()
                .GroupBy(staff => staff.Key)
                .Select(staff => staff.First())
                .OrderBy(staff => staff.Key)
                .ToList());
```

So in order to make this work, the first part is put into a compiled query,

```
public static class CompiledQueries
    {
        public static Func<DatabaseDataContext, string, IQueryable<Staff_Time_TBL>>
             sectionEmployess = CompiledQuery.Compile((DatabaseDataContext database, string section) =>
                  database.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(staff => staff.Section_Data == section));
    }
```

Than call the compiled query in a method and integrate the second part of the LINQ into that method.

For any one interested, originally I thought this was a complex enough query to warrant trying a `CompiledQuery` with the ultimate goal of improving performance of the application. However, in the end I gained very little due to the `CompiledQuery` part being so simple.